# How can I specify a layer to not be in the cluster?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I like about Leaflet.MarkerCluster that is changing the position of the markers if they are overlapping. I want the same thing, but with some markers to not be merged in a cluster. Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't tried this, but maybe something like [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet).  There's also a spiderfy available with [Leaflet.MarkerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#all-options).

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question right, but why not just add the markers you don't want to merge directly to the map instead of the MarkerCluster layer?

Comment: I tried that, but they are overlaping with the markers from MarkerCluster layer

Answer (score 0):

There's [Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision), but that will *hide* markers completely when they overlap.

Keep in mind that Leaflet.MarkerCluster does *not change* the position of the markers. It simply creates a synthetic marker for clusters, with the median position of the cluster elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need a solution which it doesn't hide the markers.